How to Resolve "UserId is Null" Error in ASP.NET Core API?
I'm encountering an issue with my ASP.NET Core API where the UserId appears to be null in the CreateStoryCommand despite being present in the CreateStoryRequest and StoryController. Here's the error message I'm receiving:
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.5",
  "title": "A 'Not Found' error has occurred.",
  "status": 404,
  "traceId": "00-e985c50c5dfd8a5c3fc981580dd24c3f-ae4d5bd6e3d3f789-00",
  "errorCodes": "customValue"
}

Here's an overview of my code structure:
StoryEntity: Contains properties including UserId.
StoryController: Handles HTTP POST requests to create a story.
CreateStoryRequest: Includes properties such as Content, Image, and UserId.
CreateStoryCommand: Represents the command for creating a story, including UserId.
CreateStoryCommandHandler: Handles the logic for creating a story.
CreateStoryAsync: Method for creating a new story entity.
Despite ensuring that UserId is present in both the request and controller, it's still showing up as null in the command handler. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
Here's a snippet of the relevant code for reference:
public class StoryEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; } 
    public string? Image { get; set; } 
    // public string? Video { get; set; } 
    private DateTime _createdAt;
    public DateTime CreatedAt
    {
        get { return _createdAt; }
        set { _createdAt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc); }
    }
    
    public DateTime ExpiresAt => CreatedAt.AddHours(24); 

    public bool IsExpired => DateTime.UtcNow > ExpiresAt;
    
    [ForeignKey("UserEntity")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; } 
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }
}
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StoryController : ApiController 
{
    private readonly ISender _mediatr;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    public StoryController(ISender mediatr, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _mediatr = mediatr;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromQuery] CreateStoryRequest request)
    {
        byte[] image = null;
        if (request.Image != null && request.Image.Length > 0)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await request.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                image = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        
        // var createStoryCommand = _mapper.Map<CreateStoryCommand>(request);
        // var createStoryResult = await _mediatr.Send(createStoryCommand); 
        var createStoryResult = await _mediatr.Send(_mapper
            .Map<CreateStoryCommand>((request, image)));

        return createStoryResult.Match(
            success => Ok(success), 
            error => Problem(error)); 
    }

     public class StoryMappingConfig 
{
    public StoryMappingConfig(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<(CreateStoryRequest request, string UserId, byte[] Image), CreateStoryCommand>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Image, src => src.Image)
            .Map(dest => dest.UserId, src => src.UserId)
            .Map(dest => dest, src => src.request);
    }
}
     public record CreateStoryCommand(
    string? Content,
    byte[]? Image,
    Guid UserId
    // string? Video
    ) : IRequest<ErrorOr<Unit>>;
          public class CreateStoryCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateStoryCommand, ErrorOr<Unit>>
{
    private readonly IStoryRepository _storyRepository;
    private readonly IImageStorageService _imageStorageService;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CreateStoryCommandHandler(IStoryRepository storyRepository, IImageStorageService imageStorageService, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _storyRepository = storyRepository;
        _imageStorageService = imageStorageService;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<Unit>> Handle(CreateStoryCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var userOrError = await _userRepository.GetUserByIdAsync(request.UserId.ToString()); 
        
        if (userOrError.IsError)
        {
            return userOrError.Errors;
        }
        
        var user = userOrError.Value;
        
        var storyEntity = new StoryEntity
        {
            Content = request.Content,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = request.UserId,
        };

        var storyResult = await _storyRepository.CreateStoryAsync(storyEntity);
        
        if (storyResult.IsError)
        {
            return storyResult.Errors;
        }

        if (request.Image != null)
        {
            var imageName = await _imageStorageService.AddStoryImageAsync(request.Image);
            if (imageName == null)
            {
                return Error.Unexpected("Avatar saving error");
            }
        
            storyEntity.Image = imageName;
        }


        var result = await _storyRepository.SaveStoryAsync(storyEntity);
        
        if (result.IsError)
        {
            return result.Errors;
        }
        
        return result;
    }

     public async Task<ErrorOr<Guid>> CreateStoryAsync(StoryEntity story)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Stories.Add(story);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return story.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Error.Failure(ex.Message);
    }
}
           public CreateStoryCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.UserId)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("UserId must not be empty").When(r => r.UserId != Guid.Empty);
        
        RuleFor(r => r.Content)
            .MaximumLength(1000).WithMessage("Content must not exceed 1000 characters.");

        RuleFor(r => r.Image)
            .Custom((image, context) =>
            {
                if (image != null && image.Length > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
                {
                    context.AddFailure("Image", "File size must not exceed 2MB");
                }
            }); 
    }
}
     public record CreateStoryRequest
{
    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} cannot exceed 1000 characters")]
    public string? Content { get; init; }
    
    [FileSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)]
    public IFormFile? Image { get; init; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{PropertyName} must not be empty")]
    public required Guid UserId { get; init; }
}
          public async Task<ErrorOr<UserEntity>> CreateUserAsync(UserEntity userEntity, string password, string role)
{
    userEntity.UserName = $"{userEntity.Email}".ToLower();

    var createUserResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userEntity, password);

    if (!createUserResult.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in createUserResult.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error creating user: {error.Description}");
        }
        return Error.Failure("Error creating user");
    }

    var addToRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userEntity, role);

    if (!addToRoleResult.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in addToRoleResult.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error adding user to role: {error.Description}");
        }
        return Error.Failure("Error adding user to role");
    }

    return userEntity;
}


I see that you have defined your mapping config as:
config.NewConfig<(CreateStoryRequest request, string UserId, byte[] Image), CreateStoryCommand>()

But you are calling it with 2 parameters:
var createStoryResult = await _mediatr.Send(_mapper
        .Map<CreateStoryCommand>((request, image)));

Judging from your mapping definition, you assign request to dest after you map dest.UserId => src.UserId. I'm not sure if order matters for your mapper or not, but could it be the case that it first maps your request to dest and then assigns UserId from a missing parameter?
        .Map(dest => dest.Image, src => src.Image)
        .Map(dest => dest.UserId, src => src.UserId)
        .Map(dest => dest, src => src.request);

